# Set up auditing for Oracle, what else do I need to perform?

Tags: oracle

I have done the following::

```
SQL> show parameters audit%r;
NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ---------------------------
audit_sys_operations                 boolean     TRUE
audit_trail                          string      DB, EXTENDED

--and

create user Bobidentified by Bob;
grant create session to Bob;
grant dba to Bob; --it's necessary
audit all by Bob;
```

I need to know everything that Bob did after connecting to the database, tell me where else to look for logs except sys.aud$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have enabled auditing with `DB, EXTENDED` option.

> All the audit logs  are stored on the database under `SYS.AUD$`table, except for records that are always written to the operating system audit trail(All audit records for `SYS` user are written to the operating system file that contains the audit trail, and not to `SYS.AUD$`).

You can query the table directly or via the following views.

```
SQL>SELECT view_name
FROM   dba_views
WHERE  view_name LIKE 'DBA%AUDIT%'
ORDER BY view_name;

VIEW_NAME
------------------------------
DBA_AUDIT_EXISTS
DBA_AUDIT_OBJECT
DBA_AUDIT_POLICIES
DBA_AUDIT_POLICY_COLUMNS
DBA_AUDIT_SESSION
DBA_AUDIT_STATEMENT
DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL
DBA_COMMON_AUDIT_TRAIL
DBA_FGA_AUDIT_TRAIL
DBA_OBJ_AUDIT_OPTS
DBA_PRIV_AUDIT_OPTS
DBA_REPAUDIT_ATTRIBUTE
DBA_REPAUDIT_COLUMN
DBA_STMT_AUDIT_OPTS

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```